# CSS menu background positioning problem

Tags: css, css-sprites

Hi i have a css menu but there is a problem and i cant figure out why it happens my problem is i have a png background with buttons normal, hover and selected states. Background image is like this

[image: Menu buttons sprite]

But i see it on page like this, with wrong order. Css code is included below. Please help!

[image]

```
#menu {padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; width:560px; height:42px; }

#menu li {float:left;}
#menu li.last {margin:0;}
#menu li a {display:block; height:42px; width:80px; padding:0; float:left; color:#666666; text-decoration:none; font-family:MuseoSans700; font-size:12px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;}
#menu li a b {position:relative; top:13px; font-weight:normal;}

#menu li a b.current { font-family: MuseoSans900;}

#menu li#home a {background: url(nav_bg.png) 0px 0px ;}
#menu li#single a {background:url(nav_bg.png) 80px 0 ;}
#menu li#dropdown a {background: url(nav_bg.png) 160px 0 ;}
#menu li#dropline a {background: url(nav_bg.png) 240px 0 ;}
#menu li#flyout a {background:url(nav_bg.png) 320px 0 ;}
#menu li#support a {background:url(nav_bg.png) 400px 0 ;}
#menu li#contact a {background: url(nav_bg.png) 480px 0 ;}

#menu li#home a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 0 -42px;}
#menu li#single a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 80px -42px;}
#menu li#dropdown a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 160px -42px;}
#menu li#dropline a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 240px -42px;}
#menu li#flyout a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 320px -42px;}
#menu li#support a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 400px -42px;}
#menu li#contact a:hover {background:url(nav_bg.png) 480px -42px;}

#menu li#home a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 0 -84px;}
#menu li#single a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 80px -84px;}
#menu li#dropdown a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 160px -84px;}
#menu li#dropline a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 240px -84px;}
#menu li#flyout a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 320px -84px;}
#menu li#support a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 400px -84px;}
#menu li#contact a.current {background:url(nav_bg.png) 480px -84px;}
```

Comment: Could you please put your HTML up too? I believe it's an issue with your `background-position` co-ordinates though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first coordinate needs to be negative. You need to move the background image to the left instead of to the right - you're getting the wrap-around effect.

For example:

```
#menu li#dropline a {background: url(nav_bg.png) 240px 0 ;}
```

should be

```
#menu li#dropline a {background: url(nav_bg.png) -240px 0 ;}
```

When you move the background image 240px to the right, it wraps around and you see the yellow background. When you move the background image 240px to the **left** you see the red background which is the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks i understood my mistake. But i'll go with pure css version below.

Comment: What you decide to use and what best answers your question are very different friend. While mdmullinax's suggestion was the way to go in this case, it does not answer your question and will not help future users who run into the same issue with background-positioning.

Answer (score 1):

can use CSS `border`s for the same effect

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/fvxLx/)

need to adjust `line-height` for `:hover` and `.current` border width changes, then assign color classes to set the `top` and `bottom` border colors.

```
#menu a {
    border-top:solid 2px;
    border-right:solid 1px #B5B6B4;
    border-bottom:solid 2px;
    border-left:solid 1px #E3E3E3;
}
#menu a:hover {border-top-width:3px;height:39px;line-height:37px;}
#menu .current {border-top-width:6px;height:36px;line-height:32px;}

#menu .lightblue {
    border-top-color:#B1C9E4;
    border-bottom-color:#B1C9E4;
}
#menu .red {
    border-top-color:#E30613;
    border-bottom-color:#E30613;
}
#menu .blue {
    border-top-color:#242457;
    border-bottom-color:#242457;
}
#menu .orange {
    border-top-color:#F18924;
    border-bottom-color:#F18924;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being a good sport and for offering a good alternative solution.